# How to add the content of a combobox in a database

Tags: c#, combobox

I want to add the content of the combobbox into my database, but it doesn't work. The content of my combobox is from the table 'Categories' who's joined with the table 'Products'. I've tried many things I have errors of conversion :

Here's my code :

```
Product p = new Product();
p.ProductName = txtNom.Text.Trim();
p.ProductDescription = txtDesc.Text.Trim();
p.ProductQuantityUsed = Convert.ToInt32(numQteUsed.Value);
p.ProductQuantityNew = Convert.ToInt32(numQteNew.Value);
p.CategoryID = cboCat.SelectedText.ToString();
db.Products.Add(p);
db.SaveChanges(); 

//Combobox
public void FillCbCategories()
{
    SamsonEntities db = new SamsonEntities();

    cboCat.Items.Clear();

    var listCat = (from cats in db.Categories                           
       select new CategoryDisplay()
       {
          CategoryID = cats.CategoryID,
          CategoryName = cats.CategoryName
       }).ToList();

    for(var i=0;i<listCat.Count;i++)
    {
       cboCat.Items.Add(listCat[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to convert a string into a int #Sajeetharan

Comment: post the error what you get!

Comment: If i use the line "p.CategoryID = cboCat.SelectedIndex;", I've got an error of conflict with the foreign key of the table 'Categories'. I made a POCO with all the properties and the property ProductCategory (CategoryID of the table 'Categories') is a string #Sajeetharan

Comment: How do you fill your cboCat? Can you post us that piece of code? What's the value of SelectedIndex when you get that error?

Comment: I updated my code with the function where I fill my cboCat #freshbm

Comment: I placed a breakpoint to see, I selected the first one, and the value it's "0" but I see null in the windows in the bottom of my Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your comments, your combobox is not binded correctly to data you send to it.

You could try setting ValueMember and DisplayMember:

```
cboCat.ValueMember = "CategoryID";
cboCat.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
```

in your method, like this:

```
public void FillCbCategories()
{
    SamsonEntities db = new SamsonEntities();

    cboCat.Items.Clear();

    var listCat = (from cats in db.Categories                           
       select new CategoryDisplay()
       {
          CategoryID = cats.CategoryID,
          CategoryName = cats.CategoryName
       }).ToList();

    for(var i=0;i<listCat.Count;i++)
    {
       cboCat.Items.Add(listCat[i]);
    }

    cboCat.ValueMember = "CategoryID";
    cboCat.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
}
```

Comment: Problem solved, I've forget to add " + 1" at the end of the line : p.CategoryID = cboCat.SelectedIndex + 1;

Comment: The only problem left is when I select a row in my grid, I want to see the value of the category in my combobox, but I can't see anything